# Backbone view collection error

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, express

I'm new to backbone and am just trying to get this view to work. I want to feed a collection data from a form that a user fills out, which will subsequently redirect the user somewhere else. However, I keep getting an undefined error, namely:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Here is the code that causes the error:

```
 //this lives within a Backbone view, as does the following constructor.
 clickSubmitRegister: function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var formData = {};
     $('#registrationForm').find('input').each(function() {
         value = $(this).val();
         thisId = $(this).attr('id');
         if (value != '') {
             formData[thisId] = value;
         }
     });
     console.log(formData); //this displays the correct data, all good
     this.collection.create(formData); //this line throws me the error
 },
```

The initialize constructor is as follows:

```
initialize: function() {
    this.collection = new app.User();
    this.render();
},
```

Comment: clickSubmitRegister gets called through a click event housed in the events object, everything is fine there and this.collection should refer to this.collections in the constructor which in turn should refer to the collection User, which lives in a file in the collections folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you properly set the click event via `this.events` object.It should work as you expected.and code you put has no problem at all.
Since `this` always refer to View instance if you set the event via backbone `events`

So there are only 2 possible reason you get the error.

1. `this` doesn't refer to the View instance.which means you changed what `this` refers explicitly or you used something like `$(this.el).on("click")` because this changes what `this` refers into clicked element.
2. this.collection got override somehow after `initialize` is called.
   ofc You have a possibility that `this.collection.create`'s replaced too.

we can't check both of them since you haven't put the full code.

So try

```
     //this lives within a Backbone view, as does the following constructor.
     clickSubmitRegister: function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         var formData = {};
         $('#registrationForm').find('input').each(function() {
             value = $(this).val();
             thisId = $(this).attr('id');
             if (value != '') {
                 formData[thisId] = value;
             }
         });
         console.log(formData); //this displays the correct data, all good
         console.log(this); //to check which object 'this' refers
         console.log(this.collection); //to check if this.collection got replaced or not
     },
```

Comment: great advice on the console.log(this), completely forgot to run it. just realized it had something to do with improper model syntax.